Forcing overfitting on simple model
I am trying to make a very simple experiment.
I want to learn a trigonometric function (say $sin(x)$) between the interval $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$. I want to make the exercise more complicated by adding noise in the training set: instead of having only one feature, I am adding a second feature, which carries no signal at all, and is just random noise. I am also adding some noise to $sin(x)$
My model should be capable of doing two things:

First, thanks to regularisation ($l1$ and $l2$ regularisation) i want the weights associated to the second feature to go to zero while training. I am regularising only the weights associated to the second feature, and this seems to work.

Second, I want to see my model overfitting, i.e. i want to see the loss function going to 0 and and validation loss starting to increase after a certain epoch, like in this image here


I am exploring a vast space of hyperparameter (number of nodes, number of epochs, kinds of regularization, noise magnitiude..) but I can't seem to find the right set of parameter to the the linked plot, despite the fact that i have only 30 samples (with noise) and 900 neurons.
Any ideas? This is the code I wrote

Probably the answer it to set the y scale on log, so to see visually when this happens more clearly.

Regarding my professional experience, the choice of activation function is the key.
Let's imagine visually what you are doing - you have a smooth infinite sin function (with noise) and you try to approximate it with a neural network. To achieve it, you added multiple layers with ReLU function. This, what ReLU lets model do, is performing a break in the prediction line regarding the input variable. More neurons and more layers mean more breaks (it's simplification but let it be for imagination's sake), which will help the model fit more and more sin's. However, it will always be too little to generalise. If I inspected model's prediction, I would expect curved angular sins with wild extrapolation.
I see you can do two things:

use sin activation layer - afterwards you should need a very minimalistic model to achieve great extrapolation, cause it's a very natural activation for your problem
use KAN, but you won't achieve good extrapolation - take a look at Figure 3.4. in Liu, Ziming, et al. "Kan: Kolmogorov-arnold networks." arXiv preprint arXiv:2404.19756 (2024).

